# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log from class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage

Tags: java, apache, google-app-engine

I have done excel sheet read and write using apache poi. But If am trying to download ms-word using same apache poi, it throws below error.
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;)V from class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
         <version>3.13</version>
     </dependency>
```

esp.setContentType("application/msword");

```
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + "xx.docx" + "\"");

    XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

    paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();

    run.setText("The endeavour started by Mohtashim, an AMU " +
               "alumni, who is the founder and the managing director " +
               "of Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd. He came up with the " +
               "website tutorialspoint.com in year 2006 with the help" +
               "of handpicked freelancers, with an array of tutorials" +
               " for computer programming languages. ");

    OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
    document.write(stream);
```

please give me solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

i use his maven dependency and write my test code

here is my code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class SampleWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();

        run.setText("The endeavour started by Mohtashim, an AMU " +
                   "alumni, who is the founder and the managing director " +
                   "of Tutorials Point (I) Pvt. Ltd. He came up with the " +
                   "website tutorialspoint.com in year 2006 with the help" +
                   "of handpicked freelancers, with an array of tutorials" +
                   " for computer programming languages. ");


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/Users/chenpengye/Documents/excel/test/test.docx");


        document.write(fileOut);

        document.close();

    }

}
```

but,not appear any error；

Answer (score 0):

please check your poi at same verson;
here is my pom.xml

```
<!-- poi excel 2003 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- poi excel 2007 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: But his POI version is also 3.13

Comment: Actually i found solution. My code is right. My local maven not updated properly. Maven clean install after i did maven update. Now its working.

Comment: @Saranya, you should post the solution as a self-answer

Answer (score 0):

please check your jar version. I think is jar version conflict caused this Error,please keep poi,poi-ooxml,poi-ooxml-schemas,poi-scratchpad have same version.